# Xamarin Forms Master Detail Page is contained within parent page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a simple master detail page, but for some reason the master page seems to be contained within the detail view.  In other words, the menu starts where the detail navigation bar ends -- I would expect the master page to start at the top of the screen.  What's the deal?

[image: Master Detail Page]

```
    public class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MasterPage(Sdk.Application context)
        {
            Title = "Master Page";

            this.Master = new MenuPage();
            this.Detail = DetailPage();

            IsPresented = true;
        }            
    }


    private NavPage DetailPage()
    {
        var result = new NavPage(new BasePage { Title = "Empty" });

        ... populate page content ...

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please check your application class, it has to contain `MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage();`, but not `MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MyMasterDetailPage());`. Also, the app theme should be `Material`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set on Android Proyect in your main Activity use AppCompat instead of FormsApplicationActivity so you see the Master get over the navigation bar:

public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity

[Here](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) is a great blog post on how to achieve that!

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard behavior for Android.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/